# Set thesis geometry

Tags: margins, memoir, geometry, thesis

I am writing my master thesis and the template that I am using has the following geometry:

```
   %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=2cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe,% show how the type block is set on the page
}
```

The result is very narrow and I think it should be a bit wider. I found another nice template that use the class memoir and the following setting:

```
\setlrmarginsandblock{37.125mm}{*}{0.9} % The first bracket specifies the spine margin, the second the edge margin and the third the ratio of the spine to the edge. Only one or two values are required and the remaining one(s) can be a star (*) to specify it is not needed. By default the edge margin is 10% smaller and 
\setulmarginsandblock{37.125mm}{*}{*} % The first bracket specifies the upper margin, the second the lower margin and the third the ratio of the upper to the lower. Only one or two values are required and the remaining one(s) can be a star (*) to specify it is not needed.
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip} % The size of marginal notes, the three values in curly brackets are \marginparsep, \marginparwidth and \marginparpush
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip} % Sets the space available for the header and footer
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*} % Sets the spacing above and below the header
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt} % Sets the spacing above the trimmed area, i.e. moved the trimmed area down the page if positive

% Comment the two lines below to reverse the position of the trimmed content on the stock paper, i.e. odd pages will have content on the right side instead of the left and even pages will have content on the left side instead of the right
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}

\checkandfixthelayout % Makes sure your specifications are correct and implements them in the document
```

The problem is that I don't know how to set my margin equal to those because I am loading the .cls file containing the whole structure and settings instead of the class memoir. 
Do you know how I can change the geometry setting to have the same results of the code above?

Comment: why you don't load these settings into your file? If I understood correctly, these settings replace your `geometry` settings. Further, if your institution requires to use a specific template why do you want to modify it?

Comment: @Yorgos I actually can't load them (i think) because they require memoir class...

Comment: ... and you are strictly required to use a specific class?

Comment: No not all, is just that in my main.tex I am using the .cls file to set all the settings. Otherwise I would have to load the class memoir instead of the .cls file but I would lose all the other settings.  (not sure if it make sense)

Comment: so why you don't modify `memoir`, with the options you want? From my very basic experience, you don't need to modify `.cls` file. You can simply load you setting in the preamble, independently the document class you use (ok, some packages work only with specific classes :P)

Comment: otherwise, you can play with different values of `geometry` options and to see which produce your desired output (you can use the margin=0.5in (let's say) option to change your margins automatically)

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=28536)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get essentially the same as in `memoir` with

```
\geometry{
  inner=37.125mm,
  outer=33.4125mm,
  top=37.125mm,
  bottom=37.125mm,
  heightrounded,
  marginparwidth=51pt,
  marginparsep=17pt,
  headsep=24pt,
}
```